# Is there a way to set a separate short title for UITabBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I'd like to be able to give my views short names for display on the tab bar, and longer (more descriptive) name when the same view is linked to in a table view. The reason is that longer names nudge up against each other on the tab bar. In a table view, there's more horizontal space, so I want to use more descriptive titles there.

Normally, the tab bar's title is set in its view controller with `self.title`. Is there a way to specifically set the tab bar title, but leave the view controller's `self.title` alone?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to select an answer if your problem is solved...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The information that is displayed in a UITabBar is queried from each UIViewController's tabBarItem" property. Similarly, a UINavigationBar queries the UIViewController's navigationItem for information.

Setting two different titles would work like this (from within you UIViewController):

```
self.tabBarItem.title = @"TabTitle";
self.navigationItem.title = @"NavigationTitle";
```

You can also specify other details like the tab bar image or the title on the "back button" via these properties.

Comment: Very helpful - I was using `self.title` rather than `self.navigationItem.title` to set my title view whose text would change frequently... kept overriding the tab bar item's text. This did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet, in your view controller's `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[self tabBarItem] setTitle:@"Short Title"];
```

Comment: But you should use the dot-notation for properties; self.tabBarItem.title = @"Short Title";

Comment: @PeyloW No, you ***shouldn't*** use dot-notation for properties.  You ***can*** use dot-notation for properties, but there is no "should" or "shouldn't" about it.

Comment: @PeyloW Did you vote me down for not using dot-notation? If so, please undo the vote because you're very wrong - dot-notation is a completely optional language feature, very separate from properties.

Comment: I totally agree with Dave and iKenndac! It's simply a matter of taste whether you use message or dot notation. The compiler translates the latter into the former.

In my answer I used the dot notation because it is a lot shorter and more familiar to non-Objective-C programmers.